# When you make a virtual PC of a certain one, can you use the programs that it contains?

Tags: virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I was wondering if is possible to use whatever programs that I have in a PC by doing a virtual machine of it, and running it in another PC without installing them again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an image of your hard drive and convert it into a virtual disk which can then be used to run a virtual machine.

See: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-a-virtual-machine-image-of-your-existing-hard-drive-windows/

Answer (score 2):

That is the point of virtualizing a system. You can use Microsofts [disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) utility to convert existing Windows installs into a vhd file which can then be imported into your hypervisor like VirtualPC, Virtualbox, VMWare, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Paragons solution [Go Virtual](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/go-virtual/).  It's very easy to use.  And supports multiple virtualization platforms.  Depending on your budget you could also have a look at [Paragon Virtualization Manager Corporate 2010](http://www.paragon-software.com/business/vm-corporate/).  It's not free but it works very nicely.